# php SESSION variables not working on 000webhost.com

Tags: php, authentication

I have made a login and register page to check the authenticity of the user.

The php file is working fine on XAMPP server. But when I uploaded it on the 000webhost.com the SESSION variables not getting stored.

```
session_start();
$email = $_POST['email'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

$check = mysqli_query($con , "Select * from sellers where email = '$email'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($check)>=1){

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($check)){
        $dbemail = $row['email'];
        $dbpass = $row['pass'];
    }

    if($email==$dbemail && md5($pass)==$dbpass){
        $cookPass = $pass;
        $pass=md5($pass);
        //setcookie('sellMail', $email, time()+(86400*30));
        $_SESSION['sellMail'] = $email;
        if(isset($_POST['remember'])){
            setcookie('email', $email, time()+(86400*30));
            setcookie('pass', $cookPass, time()+(86400*30));
        }else{
            setcookie('email', $email, time()-(86400*30));
            setcookie('pass', $cookPass, time()-(86400*30));
        }
        echo "<script>window.open('Seller.php', '_self')</script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>alert('Email or Password is Wrong')</script>";
        echo "<script>window.open('index.php', '_self')</script>";
    }
}else{
    echo "<script>alert('User Does Not exist')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('index.php', '_self')</script>";
```

php code to check login.

Comment: Please provide your code... as i have used  000webhost  and there is no issue like that ..

Comment: have you started the session with `session_start()` ? http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

Comment: I have done it but only provided the php code

Comment: I see there  is logical issue with your query and user will never be able to login untill he is the last in the database

Comment: No there wont be any problem for this because I have made it unique in database and also check it in the php code for register whether that email already exists or not so that is not a problem. The only problem is with the SESSION variables. Please solve that problem.

Comment: Some basic troubleshooting should get you to the problem quickly. Just addd `var_dump($_SESSION)` towards the top of your page: is it populated?  Try setting a session var outside of your conditional.  If that works, you know the problem is with your conditional statement.

Comment: Check your php version in 000webhost general settings. You can change it to match the php version on your local server

Answer (score 4):

Let's check this out.

Make sure that you have a *.htaccess* file in you public_html folder, If not then make a file named *.htaccess* and,

Add this piece of code in your *.htaccess* file, which will solve your issue,

```
php_flag output_buffering on
```

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if you still looking the answer, but let's check this out.

You can always try to set the session to auto started, by write this line on your .htaccess

```
php_flag session.auto_start on
```

And don't forget to delete your `session_start();` since we already started the session.

Answer (score 0):

I do all above thinks on 000webhostapp.com but it not session variable .but it will perfectly work on xampp server.

Comment: Hi mate! This is not an answer to the original question, so please delete it. What you can do instead is add a comment on the answers you followed.